# How to do a simple formula to do constant addition from cell above?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Basically I got a column of number that gets a constant number added to it, like +2 for every cell.

For example:

```
1
3
5
7
```

How do I do that in Sheet? I couldn't find a way to use the SUM formula, as I needed to reference the cell above and add +2 to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want 10 numbers, you could try

```
=sequence(10, 1, 1, 2)
```